# Objective C : Generic containing a scalar?

Tags: objective-c, generics

Xcode seems to allow this:

```
@interface Foo<__covariant ObjectType> : NSObject
@property  (nonatomic,assign) ObjectType ooo;
@end
```

However it gives an error for this:

```
Foo<int> *arrg;
```

How can I create a class whose generic class is a scalar? I need this.

Answer (score 3):

`int` is a C type, which cannot be directly represented by Objective-C reference types.

Off the top of my head, you could get around this by using `NSNumber`, which is essentially a very light-weight Objective-C wrapper around numeric types such as `int` or `float`.

Alternatively, you could use C++ templates and mix those with Objective-C. I don't know exactly how this works and what kind of restrictions you are likely to encounter, but since Objective-C++ is a thing, I would imagine that this is something it could be used for.

And indeed it looks like it can: [this blog post](https://www.sitepoint.com/using-c-and-c-in-an-ios-app-with-objective-c/) provides an intro to Objective-C++. It turns out you can have C++ ivars in your objc classes, for instance.

Comment: Using NSNumber is a problem because it hides meaningful information i.e. what type of number it is. Imagine you have 10 enum types and you store all of them in NSNumber. Then you receive an NSNumber somewhere else in your code. How can Xcode validate that it's the correct enum? It cannot. (Unless it's Swift perhaps.)

Comment: @dasj C++ template is only possible way to go. With Objective-C class, you can’t.

Comment: Can you provide a code example? It's been a few years since I did Objective-C++